# Max Mega Menu Wordpress: Change color on mega menu item on hover other item

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, megamenu

I am trying to change the color of my megamenu item when I made hover on other items in the mega menu. Please see the image as a reference:

https://www.mediafire.com/view/s5k9ltup9n7me3h/Mega_Menu_Hover.jpg/file

I used these CSS styles but didn´t work.

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link { 
    color: #85918f;
}

#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link { 
    color: white;
}
```

Any ideas?

I am using the plugin Max Mega Menu

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. If anyone needs something similar I put the code here:

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-row > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link,  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-row > ul.mega-sub-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link {
    color: #85918f;
}

#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-row > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item:hover > a.mega-menu-link  { 
    color: white !important;
}
```

Kind regards